# Where does the term “physical” come from?

Tags: etymology, history

*Physical*  in the bodily sense appears to have developed independently from its root original term *physic*. So, for instance,  you can say *you do physical exercise to keep your body, not your physic, in  good shape.*

> [Physical](https://www.etymonline.com/word/physical#etymonline_v_14915) meaning "having to do with the body, corporeal" is attested from 1780. Meaning "characterized by bodily attributes or activities" is attested from 1970. (Etymonline)

Note that you have *physique* in French  and *fisico* in Italian and Spanish  as nouns meaning *body*.

Given that, apparently,  the adjective *physical* didn’t developed the bodily connotation in English from the noun *physic*, where does it come from?

Comment: Strange. I thought *physical* was derived from the idea of a *physic* being a medical doctor or of physic relating to medicine. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

*Physic* and *physical* are obviously related. Both have to do with *medicine* and the *natural world* from the fourteenth century onward. The Middle English Dictionary entires for *[physik](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33263/track?counter=1&search_id=979636)* and *[phisical](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33261)* highlights these overlaps with quotations that show that medical practice was already closely associated with the body (minimal translations in parentheses):

> a1500(a1450) Ashmole SSecr.(Ashm 396)20/3 : He made this boke..techyng..philosophik and **phisik** doctrine, pertenyng vnto lordes for kepyng of the helth of their bodies. (He made this book teaching philosophic and **physic** doctrine, pertaining onto lords for keeping the health of their bodies.)
>
> c1450 Lydg.SSecr.Ctn.(Sln 2464)1803 : Sleep, receyved in tyme and mesure..ffroom these seknessys the boody doth Recure, Which previd is by **phisichal** prudence. 
>   (Sleep, received in time and measure ... from these sicknesses the body recovers, which is proved by **physical** prudence.)

So between this point and 1780, *physical* (but not *physic*) grew to relate specifically to corporeal bodies even independent of the medicine that treats such bodies. The OED gives a clue for how *[physical](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143120)* could drift to meaning *bodily* in one of its quotations:

> IV. Senses relating to the human body.
>
> 11.
>    a. Of or relating to the body; bodily (as distinct from mental); corporeal.
>
> 1737   (title)    Onania: or, the heinous sin of self-pollution, and all its frightful consequences... With **spiritual and physical Advice** to those who have already injur'd themselves by this abominable Practice.

*Physical* would often appear in contrast to *spiritual* and related words in texts throughout that century, until *physical* was acting to describe a corporeal body or desire:

> 1780   J. Bentham Introd. Princ. Morals & Legisl. (1789) xiv. §3   Suppose for example the physical desire has for its object the satisfying of hunger.
>
> 1778   J. R. Forster Observ. Voy. round World iv. 154   The women..are deprived in their matrimony of that share of physical love which, in a monogamous condition, would all be theirs.

Comment: So your thesis is that the sense developed from the earlier medical connotation, rather than taken, from instance, from French.

Comment: I think it developed from the earlier medical and natural connotations, yes. The word has too much history in English (15,467 hits in Eighteenth Century Collections Online alone) for me to feel safe excluding prior and contemporary English uses of *physical*.